# Procedure or function sp_Record has too many arguments specified

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

This is the code I'm using to insert records into SQL SERVER DB

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "sp_InsertEmailRecord";
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mId", memberId);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyName", dr.GetValue(0));

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

First Record insert successfully, but when it runs for second it return error

`Procedure or function sp_Record has too many arguments specified`

parameters added up

mean in first insert parameters = 2 & in next it added 2 more....

how to resolve???

Comment: Also, try not naming all of your stored procedures `sp_something`.

Comment: Reference for @JohnSaunders's pertinent comment: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your `SqlCommand` has already defined `@mId` and `@companyName` parameter since you didn't clear your parameters.

You have 2 options;

- Use `cmd.Parameters.Clear()` to clear your parameter at the end of your while statement.
- Or create a new `SqlCommand` object top of your *while statement* like `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()`

Looks like most correct way is to define your `@companyName` parameter name before your while and add it's value in while statement like John Saunders [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22351978/447156).

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlDataReader` like;

```
using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (dr != null)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "sp_InsertEmailRecord";
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mId", memberId);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@companyName");
con.Open();

while (dr.Read())
{
    cmd.Parameters["@companyName"].Value = dr.GetValue(0);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

con.Close();
```

Comment: when i try this ERROR: The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not String objects.